# Building a fast semantic MySQL search engine for private articles from scratch

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine, information-retrieval

I am working on a project that will involve *full-text* **and** *semantic* searches of articles within the site (if it's not possible to combine it, the user can select either option). These articles are subscription-based and can only be searched after logging in; so they are not accessible to external search engines or their APIs.

[I read about Sphinx](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/) for full text keywords searches (and I intend to implement it for that aspect) but I am not sure how to go about building a semantic search engine out of this. e.g. Searching for "U.S. President" should list articles that contain references to the actual names of the U.S. presidents e.g. George Washington, Bill Clinton (or William Jefferson Clinton).

I have ideas that maybe a sort of tagging system can be used to relate various keywords e.g. relate President to George Washington and President to Bill Clinton, but since the data is really huge and many such relations will exist I don't know how to further this idea.

Please advice me on how to go about building a semantic search engine (I guess Sphinx can handle the full-text keyword search) from scratch. Otherwise, please inform me of any internet-based resources or if there are already existent software in any language that I can integrate into my application.

P.S. My database of choice is MySQL (please advice if another database system is more suitable for the task), and I prefer to program in PHP but if I need to learn Python or any other language that will be more effective to this task, I will be willing.

I already searched at [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). I think it's more flexible than Sphinx. Solr supports full-text search and I believe has add-ons for semantic support (like [siren](http://siren.sindice.com/download.html)). Solr is the serverized version of Lucene.

Solr supports a SynonymFilter: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter

This post discusses some strategies for optimizing content retrieval http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/optimizing-findability-lucene-and-solr

Comment: Thank you! I just read the SIREn article. Would this mean that I need to create RDF tags on each of the articles, or does it automate it? Also what languages does SIREn work with? Both questions are not answered on the SIREn site.

I am wondering if it is possible to generate RDF tags automatically... I read of AR semantics http://www.appliedrelevance.com/2011/09/28/ar-semantics-for-apache-solr/ for Solr but there is no information on how to get it.

Comment: Based on the getting started section it looks like siren is Java. (I believe Sphinx is C++).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll accept your answer because it gives a good start.

Although I still wonder how to get AR Semantics or any other that generates RDF tags automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This book may be useful for someone reading this thread. I just found it on Amazon.

[http://www.amazon.com/E-Librarian-Service-User-Friendly-Libraries-X-media-publishing/dp/3642177425](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642177425)