# how to make search based on semantics in mysql

Tags: php, database-design, search-engine, semantics

I am developing an appliation in PHP which requires to search things. But I want to search things based on meanings as someone search for term home I want to include things which contain 'house' as keyword. Any way oor any library to implement these?

Comment: fulltext search will help...

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a fast semantic MySQL search engine for private articles from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987883/building-a-fast-semantic-mysql-search-engine-for-private-articles-from-scratch)

Comment: I don't think there is any clear cut solution for this available yet. But [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) would make it easier. It's based on Apache Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

For complex searching you probably want to look in to a search server such as [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).